# Selenium 2.0 Robot class on remote host

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, awtrobot

I just write a test which is supposed to download pdf files via webApp(Yep, I know, I should not do it on selenium, but You know, Orders.)

What do I need?

For diffrent scenarios I have to download difrent pdf, rename it and place to custom catalog. So, I have to handle with system modal window.
Everything works great, so test is run on remote host, and when I click to download the file I handle the system modal window(I used robotil package, it is extended robot class which allow us use robot class on remote host) so I use robotil class to type path to file, and file name on system modal and then click "Enter" to confirm and save the file. This is everything I need and it works, so where is the problem? here: SOMEONE should be logged to remote host, if Im logged via rdp and looks at screen(and doing my stuff on my host) then everything is great, but for the case when no one is logged, it looks like that during tests webbrowswer do not have a FOCUS, so everytime robotil class do some action this action is not focused on webbroswer(as it should).

test class:

```
@Test
public void compareDeposits() throws Exception {

    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, homePage);

    PrintDepositsPage printDepositsPage = (PrintDepositsPage) homePage.openViaUrl(Data.baseUrl).openViewViaTopMenu(
            ETopMenuItem.PrintDeposits);

    ((PrintDepositsPage) printDepositsPage).goToPrintedDepositsTab();
    printDepositsPage.getPrintedDepositsDateRangeFromInput().click();
    printDepositsPage.getPrintedDepositsDateRangeFromInput().clear();
    printDepositsPage.getPrintedDepositsGoButton().click();
    printDepositsPage.getFirstRecordOnPrintedDepositsTab().click();
    handler.getRobot().mouseClick(371, 274, InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);// get focus
    printDepositsPage.getPrintButtonEnabled().click();

    handler.downloadFile("DepositTest");
```

handler object declaration:

```
class SystemModalWindowHandler {

private RemoteWebDriver driver;
private Date date = new Date();
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy/mm/dd");
private String extendedTestName = dateFormat.format(date).replace("/", ".") + ".pdf";
private Robotil robotil = new Robotil("xxxxx", 6667);

public Robotil getRobot(){
    return robotil;
}

public void downloadFile(String testFileName) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    boolean continueBool = true;
    while (continueBool) {
        String pathToTestFile = new String("C:\\DiffPdfData\\" + testFileName + "\\"
                + extendedTestName);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        for (int i = 0; i < pathToTestFile.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(pathToTestFile.charAt(i)) + " = "
                    + (int) pathToTestFile.charAt(i));
            if ((int) pathToTestFile.charAt(i) == 58) {

                robotil.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                robotil.pressAndReleaseKey(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                robotil.releaseKey(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }
            else {
                robotil.pressAndReleaseKey(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar((int) pathToTestFile.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        robotil.pressAndReleaseKey(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        continueBool = false;
    }
```

is there any way to get focus on webbrowser when no one is logged in?.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that using the mentioned strategy you won't be able to accomplish it without logged-in user. So I suggest you to use a simpler solution.

You can configure Firefox the directly download the files - [File types and download actions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions)

If you don't want to hardcode the setting for your browser, you can setup a specific FF profile only for your tests, where you can configure where you want the files to be downloaded.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Chrome Driver:

```
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: ah, I have use chrome webdriver :( and my company app is supported only by chrome, and as far I know there is no way to change default download path for chrome webdriver (DesiredCapabilities for chrome does not work for downloadPath)